# Modify template.php for custom HTML

Tags: theming

It was suggested the below script in template.php might work to assist in creating a modified HTML page.

```
<?php
function YOUTHEME_preprocess_html (&$vars) {
if (module_exists('path')) {
$alias = drupal_get_path_alias(str_replace('/edit','',$_GET['q']));
if ($alias != $_GET['q']) {
$template_filename = 'html';
foreach (explode('/', $alias) as $path_part) {
$template_filename = $template_filename . '__' . $path_part;
$vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = $template_filename;
      }
    }
  }
}
?>
```

I tried it but broke my site. Do I need to copy just the code minus the php brackets? Use my exact subtheme name to replace YOURTHEME and then create my html--foo.tpl.php to correspond?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I am trying to customise a particular node with html that will not work in a block as such.

Answer (score 0):

you can try `function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook)` to override theme theme_hook_suggestions.  More detail you will find [here](https://drupal.org/comment/4662688#comment-4662688).

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare black_premium_html_head_alter()   getting this now when changing template. I tried instructions on your link as well and it didn't break the site- just didn't work sorry.

Comment: Why are you trying to redeclare any function? Use previously declared function to take effect as you want

Comment: Not trying to redeclare, that is just output error after modifying template.php command drush cc all

Comment: Anyway this is more confusing for me because I'm not sure what I should leave in page--foo.tpl.php where it is mix of php code and html and page I need to embed is not even same doc type!